# Spring Boot Slf4j change log timestamp to use UTC timezone

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, lombok

Spring boot app with default logger settings and using lombok's `@Slf4j`

Prints logs like:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-02-26T11:25:57.485-05:00" ..........}
```

The time shown `11:25` is in `EST` or `NewYork` timezone

How do we change this to log timestamp in the `UTC` timezone?

I have tried setting:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    dateformat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, UTC
```

Also setting JVM level timezone by using:

```
@PostConstruct
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

and have also tried configuring in `application.yaml`:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS,UTC"} [%p] [%t] %M\(%F:%L\) - %msg%n'
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem that happens to you described in the [slf4j docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#date)

After checking the date format I've noticed that indeed the dateformat

```
logging:
   pattern:
     dateformat: you date format
```

Is not working for some reason

But if you will use the console configuration it will work

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%date{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", UTC} [%p] [%t] %M\(%F:%L\) - %msg%n'
```

Notice that the apostrophes should be only on the date format and not on the timezone, because the time sone is the second parameter for the slf4j date format parser function.

As mentioned in the slf4j docs:

> COMMON ERROR - Given that the comma ',' character is interpreted as the parameter separator, the pattern HH:mm:ss,SSS will be interpreted as the pattern HM:mm:ss and the timezone SSS. If you wish to include a comma in your date pattern, then simply enclose the pattern between quotes. For example, %date{"HH:mm:ss,SSS"}.

Comment: Unfortunately, Its not working for me. But on investigating I've found that Spring boot or logback not even considering this property, Since I've also tried changing (other than timezone) dateformat but no impact

Comment: @Mayur maybe try to clean your compiled files, if you are using gradle/maven, just run the clean command

Comment: That solution helped me with setting time zone in Graphhopper logs which also uses sl4j as a logging provider.

Answer (score 1):

So the provided answer doesn't seem to work. This format works though:

%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}{America/Denver}

Answer (score 0):

Below one worked for me to Change from UTC to CDT.

%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ","America/Chicago"}

Answer (score 0):

Using SpringBoot 2.6.6 with (the default) logback, this worked for me:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    dateformat: "\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX\", UTC"
```

The resulting timestamp looks like this: `2022-04-27T13:41:38,500Z`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my spring boot application log timezone by adding `{GMT+x}` eg: (`{GMT+0}`) to my LOG_PATTERN . since you are also using logback `@slf4j` annotation and spring boot it should work.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS,UTC"}{GMT+0} [%p] [%t] %M\(%F:%L\) - %msg%n'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, America/Chicago}
```

See document https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html  Search TimeZone